# How to handle keyboard shortcuts

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-shortcuts

I'm writing a Flutter app and want to handle keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl+I in the web version of the app.

*Small disclaimer*: Looks like the Flutter API around shortcuts has changed recently. The online documentation that I found was outdated. I'm using `Flutter 1.19.0-0.0.pre • channel dev`.

I found the [Actions API Design](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1A9yald55O_C6Weqp4tOtyMisfOC1ZC0UMq7Yc-pNfVQ/edit) document which feels like the current available API. Based on the example in the document I implemented this short snippet:

```
class MyIntent extends Intent {}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: Shortcuts(
        shortcuts: {
          LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.control): MyIntent(),
        },
        child: Actions(
          actions: {
            MyIntent: CallbackAction(onInvoke: (i) {
              print('Hello World!!!');
              return null;
            }),
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Hello World',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, it does not react on pressing the control-key and does not output the expected message. While debugging into the code I noticed that the instance of `ShortcutManager` that does handle the key event does not contain my key combination as specified, but nine other key combinations.

Does anybody know, how to use the `Shortcuts` and `Actions` API to react on keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 5):

In your example, you have the right idea, but what you're missing is a `Focus` widget.  If the widget doesn't have focus, then its ancestor `Shortcuts` widget won't receive the key event in order to handle it.

See this [Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a824f267aac76bbd063811f83bda9a13) to see what I mean. The example adds a new "Homework" when the "Alt+N" keys are pressed.

You can also use the [FocusableActionDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusableActionDetector-class.html) which combines `Shortcuts`, `Actions`, and mouse hover handling into one widget.

Comment: the dartpad example worked fine for me, but is there any way to detect when the keys are released? 



I am unable to wrap `RawKeyboardListener` around `FocusableActionDetector ` to get the latest keyup/down event as it is throwing `'!ancestors.contains(child)': The supplied child is already an ancestor of this node. Loops are not allowed` error.

How do I listen the latest keypress events when I am using `FocusableActionDetector` or `Shortcuts`?

Comment: It's strange how they used Intent here, like it's a pretty useless class and kinda annoying. This is not very "flutter", seems over engineered.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add something to [Greg's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61960260/how-to-handle-keyboard-shortcuts/63622833#63622833) above

If you want to add more than one key in a single shortcut, then your code will be:

```
shortcuts: <ShortcutActivator, Intent> {
    LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.control, LogicalKeyboardKey.keyL): 
    MyIntent(),
},
```